# How to dynamically set an ENV variable using a Dockerfile

Tags: variables, set, dockerfile, environment

I have a Dockerfile that has access to a variable that indicates the environment it is being targeted to.  Our CICD pipeline makes this environment variable available to the Dockerfile and I can test for a particular environment using "Run if $Environment =".

When I detect a "test" environment, I need to create another environment variable on-the-fly.  However, code like this doesn't seem to work:

RUN if $Environment="test" ; then ; /
 ENV NewEnvironmentVariable = "test" ; /
fi

The get "ENV" not found when it runs.  So obviously, you can't use ENV this way within a RUN .. if.

I CAN however, use bash commands to export the variable, but it's probably creating this export in a different context, so, the Dockerfile doesn't have access to it.  I would have thought that exporting it would make the new environment variable to the Docker file (when it returns from the "if" block.

In short, I simply need to evaluate and existing environment variable and if it contains the value I'm looking for it will create a new ENV variable just as if I have done "ENV MyNewVar=1".

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: using bash commands is the way to go and will create the variable in the right context. have you tried it already and it didn't work? if so can you paste the code?

Comment: It "works" in the sense that the bash commands execute and return no errors. However, I need to have the variable I created in the curl exported to the dockerfile context (if that's possible). This might explain it better: 

  `FROM .....

RUN if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" = "dev" ] ; then \
 curl -sL ... ; \
 export HOST=10.152.11.73 ; \
 export PORT=6060 ; \
 export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentpath:myagent/lib.so ; \
 env ; \
 fi

 -- if the above script was executed, I want to have an JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable set
 ENV_APP_NAME=mySpringBootApp

 CMD["service"]

 `

Comment: seems to me that all this logic can go in a script in CMD. So instead of just calling service now in CMD you could call a script (start.sh) and in that script put all this logic and call service at the end. I see no benefit from having all this done at BUILD time. If you update the Dockerfile I can rewrite it to explain better

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.  Let me give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: I created a bash script to create the environment variable.  The script works find when I issue "env | grep "JAVA"" I can see JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is created.  However, when the script exits, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS doesn't exist.  I thought that "export" would do the trick.  I do like using the script, it's cleaner.  But if I can get that variable exported to the calling shell I'd have a working solution.

Comment: Looks like export is for a child process (in other words if my script called a script it would see the variable).  I need to have this env variable available to the parent.

Comment: Bash script is working fine with a few tweaks.  THanks for your help.